# braintree node js using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, paypal, braintree

Braintree find customer using customer id returns a response object that is containing function as a value of getgateway(key).. and firebase rejecting to push the response into the database...

with the error

> Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains a function in
>   property
>   'Wallets.qN5RmUgatwbianIuYYHmLX6GGrC3.Accountdetails.creditCards.0.getGateway'
>   with contents: () => gateway

Has anyone come across this issue and solved it? Here is my code:

```
find braintree user result:  Customer {
  id: '185946869',
  merchantId: 'hjctjwrqxh6t3qhf',
  firstName: 'kayak@gmail.com',
  lastName: '',
  company: '',
  email: 'kayak@gmail.com',
  phone: '',
  fax: '',
  website: '',
  createdAt: '2018-02-16T10:28:47Z',
  updatedAt: '2018-02-16T10:29:15Z',
  customFields: '',
  creditCards: 
   [ CreditCard {
       bin: '411111',
       cardType: 'Visa',
       cardholderName: null,
       commercial: 'Unknown',
       countryOfIssuance: 'Unknown',
       createdAt: '2018-02-16T10:29:15Z',
       customerId: '185946869',
       customerLocation: 'US',
       debit: 'Unknown',
       default: true,
       durbinRegulated: 'Unknown',
       expirationMonth: '02',
       expirationYear: '2019',
       expired: false,
       healthcare: 'Unknown',
       imageUrl: 'https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox',
       issuingBank: 'Unknown',
       last4: '1111',
       payroll: 'Unknown',
       prepaid: 'Unknown',
       productId: 'Unknown',
       subscriptions: [],
       token: 'fbm3yx',
       uniqueNumberIdentifier: '1077b77aa2b0c0821e51ad010e31ee93',
       updatedAt: '2018-02-16T10:29:17Z',
       venmoSdk: false,
       verifications: [],

       getGateway: [Function],

       maskedNumber: '411111******1111',
       expirationDate: '02/2019' } ],
  addresses: [],
  getGateway: [Function],
  paymentMethods: 
   [ CreditCard {
       bin: '411111',
       cardType: 'Visa',
       cardholderName: null,
       commercial: 'Unknown',
       countryOfIssuance: 'Unknown',
       createdAt: '2018-02-16T10:29:15Z',
       customerId: '185946869',
       customerLocation: 'US',
       debit: 'Unknown',
       default: true,
       durbinRegulated: 'Unknown',
       expirationMonth: '02',
       expirationYear: '2019',
       expired: false,
       healthcare: 'Unknown',
       imageUrl: 'https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox',
       issuingBank: 'Unknown',
       last4: '1111',
       payroll: 'Unknown',
       prepaid: 'Unknown',
       productId: 'Unknown',
       subscriptions: [],
       token: 'fbm3yx',
       uniqueNumberIdentifier: '1077b77aa2b0c0821e51ad010e31ee93',
       updatedAt: '2018-02-16T10:29:17Z',
       venmoSdk: false,
       verifications: [],
       getGateway: [Function],
       maskedNumber: '411111******1111',
       expirationDate: '02/2019' } ] }
```

I have been having issues with the Braintree respose object for the last several days.  Is it an issue with my API calls? Or has something changed regarding the API service.

Comment: What version of Braintree's Node SDK are you using? Have you made any changes to your dependency versions or API calls to Braintree recently?

Comment: "braintree": "^2.3.0". no i didnt do any  changes in dependencies , after the failure of braintree api calls did some debugging and found this is the problem.. if the response is as simple object then i am normalizing the data but this response seems to be bit complex . thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct ... We've recently came across the same issue and reached out to Braintree. There is no issue with your call ... the change is in the [Braintree node package](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node), though undocumented.

Unfortunately, there is no flag that we can use to indicate to the Braintree API not to send back getGateway property as part of the `transaction.sale()` result object.

Like you, the solution we're developing is to iterate through the result object and filter out any property that is a `typeof function`.

Supposedly Braintree is currently looking at removing the getGateway method from the response object altogether, though they don't have a firm commitment or a timeline for this change.